# Rails3: Initial user profile form, REST or not? Which URL would you suggest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, routes

I am new to Rails and its all-REST concept.

I want users to fill a short form (their profile info) once they sign up.
Unfortunately, the `/users/edit` REST URL already contains a password modification dialog.
I don't want the initial short form to contain this password modification dialog, it would be very confusing.

What URL should I use? How to route it?

*Note: I am using Devise for authentication.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first answer that comes to my mind is probably not the best option but it should get you started on the right path.

When a user signs up, in your users/create action do something like this:

`redirect_to edit_user_url(@user, :survey => "1") and return`

and then in your users/edit action do this:

```
if params[:survey] == "1"
    render :action => "survey" and return
end
```

In your views/users folder make sure you've got survey.html.erb or short_form.html.erb or whatever you wanna call it. Put your form there. If it's going to be editing the user then make it work like a standard edit form but just leave out things like the password or whatever.

This way you can link to the survey (or short form, whatever) but it will only normally show up when they create an account.

If you want to show the edit user view but only want to leave out one option (the password field) then you might want to consider linking to the edit action with :new_user => "1" like I did above but then in the view test for that param and if it's there don't show the password field but if it isn't show it. That's probably not the best idea either, but it's what I'd lean towards doing if you need just one or a few fields to not show up but otherwise have the form the same. Some people think conditional statements in views is uncouth but if it's done sparingly I think it's fine.

If what you're looking to do is have a completely unrelated action, something that has absolutely nothing to do with editing the user then you'll want to add a new RESTful action to the model. Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html especially the section entitled "2.9 Adding More RESTful Actions".